# Visual Studio 2013 - Rename SSIS Solution (Package, object files, everything)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, ssis

I am using Visual Studio 2013 Data Tools and I have an existing built solution that I want to duplicate and rename.

When copying the new solution over, let's call it 'X' and going to **Solution Explorer** and renaming the solution to 'Y' I am able to rename it but all child elements (the packages, objects) keep the same name 'X'.

I tried renaming the package.dtsx and the solution to 'Y' but then it broke when trying to reload the solution.

How can I rename **everything**?

Comment: Could you expand on "but then it broke when trying to reload the solution"

Comment: @billinkc I right click 'solution explorer -> solution', hit rename and change it to 'Y'. Then I rename the package to 'Y'. I close the solution. When I open it again I get the error: "One or more projects in this solution were not loaded correctly" and I'm unable to open the solution

Answer (score 1):

It works for me.

I rename the solution, the project and a package. Save All and then close the solution.

At this point, I cannot reopen the previous solution because X.sln/X.dtproj no longer exists through the rename. What gets confusing is that the rename does not rename folders (thus the Y.sln is in the X folder and all the SSIS artifacts remain in the X subfolder).

[image: SaveAll]